# EF Core failing to save modified entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an application that's using EF Core (version 5.0.5) with a MySql database. My context is setup so that `QueryTrackingBehavior` is `NoTracking` and when i try to save a modified entity I get the following exception:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See ...

The application uses the Repository/UnitOfWork pattern but the code essentially boils down to:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int Counter {get; set;}
}

public async Task UpdateCounter(Guid id)
{
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>()
        .UseMySql(CONNECTION_STRING, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(CONNECTION_STRING), options =>
        {
            options.UseNetTopologySuite();
        })
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        
    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    
    MyEntity entity = await context.Set<MyEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    
    entity.Counter += 1;
    
    context.Update(entity);
    
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

As a test, I stored the result of `context.Update(entity);` to a variable so I could inspect it in debug and it looks correct (as far as I understand), the state says it's modified but yet I still get the exception.

I did some reading online and found a few suggestions and tried replacing `context.Update(entity);` with:

```
context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Which had the same result. I also tried:

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Which also had the same result. In my reading I was a little confused what the difference between these three lines even were.

My main question is: Why is EF Core failing to save my entity?

**Edit**
A couple pieces of information that might be important:

- `MyEntity.Counter` is set as a concurrency token and has a default value
- Adding a new entity to the database works no problem, it's just the update that is causing the exception

Comment: Do you have a primary key?  When you do a Insert with a primary key you will get zero rows changes when the key is in the database and then you need to use update.  Likewise if you do do an update and the key is not in the database you will get zero rows changed and then you need to do an insert.

Comment: `MyEntity.Id` is the primary key and it does exist in the database so I would expect that update would affect 1 row

Comment: No.  Update only changes existing keys.

Comment: Apparently the problem is the non-tracking query and updating a field marked as concurrency token w/o first retrieving the original value (or letting EFC change tracker know the original value by first attaching before modification). In general `Update` method and all other "forced update" methods you've mentioned won't work with modified concurrency token field.

Comment: @IvanStoev you're right. I removed the `IsConcurrencyToken()` in my `DbContext` and it works. In hindsight that should have been pretty obvious. I'm going to try leaving tracking on by default and using `AsNoTracking()` when it's needed. A question I should have asked before all this was, is there a better way of having a row with a counter in it? Each one of my rows needs to keep a count of certain objects and I want to ensure they handle concurrent writes correctly. Using a concurrency token seems like the right approach to me be but I may be wrong

Comment: At last!  Thanks guys.   Removing the IsConcurrencyToken() worked for me also.

Each one of my Tables had a TimeStamp and nothing was updating. I just removed the Field and all is well.